# How to be sure about "MetaMask web3 Provider" connection?

Tags: web3js, metamask, testrpc, javascript, signature

Note: This question is related to this : ["Updated :" How to see "output" of "web3.personal.sign" in "browser"? ("Method personal_sign not supported")](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/updated-how-to-see-output-of-web3-personal-sign-in-browser-method-p/54884?noredirect=1#comment65013_54884)

I do following steps to sign a message using `web3.personal.sign`. However, I am not to `MetaMask`. (Note: apparently, `web3.personal.sign` is not supported by `testRPC`.)
Here are steps that I do:

(1) I open `cmd` and run `testrpc`

(2) I click on `MetaMask` icon and selecting `localhost 8545`

(3) I select one of `private keys` generated by `testrpc`

(4) I select `import account` from `MetaMask` and paste this `private key` in text box of `Paste your private key string here`

(5) now balance of this address is `100 eth`

(6) I insert this address (public key) in `web3.personal.sign` function to sign the message (Please see the full code below)

(7) I open `html` file by `Google Chrome`

(8) I receive this messages : `No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!` and  `Error: Method personal_sign not supported`. Here is screen shot: https://ibb.co/i93oRy

Here is the full code for signing a message using `web3.personal.sign`:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EthereumJS - Browser Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/master/dist/ethereumjs-abi/ethereumjs-abi-0.6.5.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/ethereum/web3.js/develop/dist/web3.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

  <script>

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

   // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  }

//  var Web3 
//  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

  function constructPaymentMessage(contractAddress, amount) 
  {
  return ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [contractAddress, amount],
  );
  }

  var message = constructPaymentMessage("message to be signed", 100);
  console.log(message);

  web3.personal.sign("0x" + message.toString("hex"), "0x01e7D1D50804fDc2fD5A134081076A8E487Ca747", function(err, signature) {
  console.log(signature);
  console.log(err);
  // Be sure to make use of the signature only here.
  // It will not be defined until this callback is invoked.
});

}) 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Apparently, I am not connected to `MetaMask` and if so, How can I solve this problem?**

Here is screen shot of `MetaMask` when is opened and connected to `localhost 8545` (As you can see the balance of `testRPC` address is `100 eth`) :

[image]

Comment: Show us a screenshot of your Metamask extension opened and connected to the network

Comment: When you go to [this page](https://shawntabrizi.com/ethbalance/) using chrome, what does your console say?

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi   `Web3 Detected! MetamaskInpageProvider` screen shot : https://ibb.co/gZfwDd

Answer (score 1):

A web server is required for a Metamask to interact with your webpage:

[Http(s) - Web Server Required](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#globe_with_meridians-https---web-server-required)

> Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps running on file://. Please use a local server for development.

Deploy your page to a local server in order to detect Metamask.

Comment: Yes apparently. This answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46400/23024 also says this. However it suggests also using `https://mainnet.infura.io/<APIKEY>` instead of `localhost 8545` if I run my page locally. So, can i use `"https://mainnet.infura.io/noapikey"` that is used in the page you shared ? Thanks

Comment: also if i connect to `Ropsten` by `Parity` but i use `localhost 8545` in my `html` file, Does it work ? Thanks

Comment: The problem is if you use infura as your connection to the network, you will not have an "account" loaded with your web3 provider. You can of course put your private key and stuff within your code so that you are able to use your account, but usually using something like Metamask is better. Infura is a good replacement if you are simply doing read operations.

Comment: Thank you, so in this case, I have to use ex. `Parity` to connect to ex. `Ropsten` and then use `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));` in top of `JavaScript` code and running this `JS` file using `node filename.js` ? Is there any better way? Thanks